# What is a good way to prevent overflows when converting float to bigint in Python?

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer-overflow

When trimming large decimals resulting from divisions I am getting an overflow problem. 
E.g.:

```py
>>> from math import floor
>>> int(100000000000000123.1)
100000000000000128
>>> floor(100000000000000123.1)
100000000000000128
```

From the type is seems that the number is a plain float and it cannot be stored at the needed precision. So even with floor() I run into the same issue.
Is there a better data type to store 'long floats/doubles'? And if yes, how can I force divisions of bigints not to return a low precision float?
btw, I'm using Python 3.6 64-bit.

Comment: If you want to store a precise decimal value, there is the [`Decimal` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Comment: You should just use integers all the way through. This is an inherent problem with floating point.

Comment: The problem is that `100000000000000123.1` isn't precise as a float to begin with. Try `a = 100000000000000123.1`, then `a` on the Python prompt. Thus, you're trying to convert an imprecise floating point number to an integer.

Comment: There's `from fractions import Fraction` if you need common fractions for division. They use Python's unlimited `int`, so you can store any rational number (memory allowing) exactly and not lose precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the stdlib module [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html)

```
import decimal

long_number = '100000000000000123.1'  # note that this is a string
your_decimal = decimal.Decimal(long_number)
```

`Decimal`s are smart enough to return `Decimal` objects from any standard mathematic operation

```
result = your_decimal - 123
assert isinstance(result, decimal.Decimal)
assert your_decimal == decimal.Decimal('100000000000000000.1')
```

Comment: Yes, using the Decimal type changed things.... However the usage of Decimal is not completely stable. Over the course of a few iterations it turned back into an integer. I can force the conversion during the flow, but the value is still overflowing somewhere. I'll dig a bit deeper to isolate the problem.

Comment: Ok. I've found where it bounces back to int. Apparently floor() will convert it back to int. Doing something in the likes of `Decimal(floor(a/10))` will do the trick. It just looks ugly :)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Aetonyx `math.floor` will definitely give you back an `int`. `Decimal`s have a `quantize` method that will do what you want. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize

Comment: Not quite as quantize() will round the result (2.7 will result 3). And yes, I can set the rounding mode to floor, but what I am looking for is the analogous function to int divide (floor of -2.7 is -3 and not -2). In any case, the operator I was looking for would be the // operator. And for the divide by 10 stuff, I can just use the decimal shift. Thanks again for pointing me to this module. It is really cool stuff.

Comment: `assert Decimal('-2.7').quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN) == Decimal('-2')` There's rounding for [everything](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_DOWN)